# Flutter - setState() does not update list in widget

Tags: flutter, refresh, setstate

I am currently on a project as part of my training. I need to create a schedule Flutter application. However, I have a problem updating the list to display.

I have a method **handleRefresh** that is called : at initialization to load the list (called in initState()), when I refresh the page with a refreshIndicator.

the list loads well at launch, but when it is subsequently modified, the refresh method does not work.

To refresh the display, I clear the list and then I add the new elements. But, it does not work.
if I decide not to clear the list and just add the elements, it works but I have duplicates because I didn't clear the list before adding new elements.

So, do you know why clearing the list prevents it from being refreshed ?

*Excuse me for my English, I don't speak it very well, I'm French*

```
class _PageControlesState extends State<PageControles>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageControles> {
  List<SemaineCc> _listeSemaineCc = new List<SemaineCc>();

  Temp body;

  List<Widget> _semaineCcWrapper;

  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _semaineCcWrapper = new List<Widget>();
    _semaineCcWrapper.add(new Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ));
    _handleRefresh(debut: true);
  }

  @override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 30),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Text(
              'Contrôles',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).data.textTheme.headline1.color,
              )
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
        onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
        child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-30-50-30-27,
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child:  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 60
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 0),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Column(
                        children: _semaineCcWrapper,
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => PopupAjouterControleUI(),
          ).then((value) {
            print(value);
            if(value!=null)
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( SnackBar(content: Text('sauvegarde reussie')));
             _handleRefresh();
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
    );
  }




  Future<void> _handleRefresh({bool debut = false}) {
      return fetchCc().then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _semaineCcWrapper.clear();

          _listeSemaineCc = value;
          for (SemaineCc semaineCc in value) {
            _semaineCcWrapper.add(SemaineCcUI(semaineCc: semaineCc));
          }
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your post and add an example of how the data which comes from `fetchCc()` looks like? Before and after a refresh operation. Also, why do you need the `GlobalKey` there? You don't seem to be using it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i solved the problem yesterday. I will post my patch. Thank you again !!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem yesterday,

I dont know why but there is a kind of persistence in the display when displaying a list of stateFulWidget.

For example: when I have a list of 3 items (3 stateFulWidget) in this order : A, B, C
If I want to remove B and refresh after, we will see A, B instead of A, C. I dont know why but that's what happens.

So to solve this problem, instead of removing B, I place all the informations of C in B so B become C and then I delete the previous C. It works for me.

I hope that can help you ^^.

*Excuse me again for my English, I don't speak it very well, I'm French*